# Integrate MarkerClusterer with database driven Google Map V3

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to integrate [MarkerCluster](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html) with my database driven Google map and have been struggling to get it to work.

The first code example generates a map from a database that already has the multiple markers lat/long.

The second bit of code is a simple version of Marker Cluster.

How can I combine the two? Both are setup for V3 of the api.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/phpsqlajax_genxml.php ", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>
```

The example below is Marker Cluster:

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
var options = {
  'zoom': 13,
  'center': center,
  'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,
      data.photos[i].longitude);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latLng});
  markers.push(marker);
}
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a lot of trial and error and some help from @geocodezip:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var cluster = [];
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/phpsqlajax_genxml.php ", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent("Info on member here");
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
          cluster.push(marker);
        }
        var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,cluster);
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>
```

Comment: how do i get default icons instead of the custom ones? asking because no other examples that use cluster method with database method and downloadurl xml method have examples of that.

Comment: i mean these icons: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-clustering . all the way zoomed in can have the custom ones, but when zoomed out i don't see those circular colored icons using your example code.

Comment: Hi did you figure this out? I am stuck on this also

Answer (score 1):

You asked "How can I integrate the second example into the first"?

Port the first example to the v3 API, [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html) translated from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial may help.

Then add [clustering](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered.html) and custom infowindows (which you have in your second example).

Comment: A link to your map where you are having issues might allow us to give you some advice.

Comment: Just trying to convert the first bit of code into v3 of the api. Doesn't seem to be working at the moment, the map is just blank when using google's tutorial - https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Comment: I get a javascript error on the link you provided above: 
Timestamp: 06/19/2012 07:50:42 AM
Error: missing ] in index expression
Source File: http://www.mediwales.com/mapping/test/
Line: 38, Column: 31
Source Code:
          var name = markers[[]i].getAttribute("name");

Comment: That is an error in that tutorial. If you look at the ["source"](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles/phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_map_v3.html), it is correct.

Comment: Awesome, got spotting. Right at least now that'll give me a chance of getting it to work with the other stuff!

Comment: Entered an issue in the issue tracker: <http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4223>

Comment: Here is (hopefully) a working [link](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4223) to the issue.